# Manipulating triple sums

Tags: summation, solution-verification

> $$ \sum_{i,j,k=0}^n \frac{1}{3^{i+j+k} }  $$

$$ \sum_{i,j,k=0}^n \frac{1}{3^{i+j+k} } = \sum_{j=0}^n \sum_{i=0}^n \left[\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{3^{i+j+k }}\right]$$

Now notice that the inner most sum is independent of $i$ and $j$, hence:

$$  \sum_{j=0}^n \sum_{i=0}^n \left[\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{3^{i+j+k }}\right] = \left[\sum_{j=0}^n \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{1}{3^{i+j} } \right]\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{3^k}$$

And now notice the bracketed inner sum is independent of $j$ hence:

$$   \left[\sum_{j=0}^n \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{1}{3^{i+j} } \right]\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{3^k} =  \sum_{j=0}^n \frac{1}{3^j} \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{1}{3^{i} } \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{3^k}$$

Now notice all three of these are actually the same sum and hence:

$$ \sum_{i,j,k=0}^n \frac{1}{3^{i+j+k} }  = \left( \sum_{j=0}^n \frac{1}{3^j} \right)^3$$

For some reason my conclusion is wrong.. why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with your conclusion. It is tantamount to an expansion of $(\sum_{i=0}^n 1/3^i)^3$.

Comment: @Raffaele I tested numerically, and I am correct.